# numpy switch axes and reshape

Tags: python, numpy

I have some geophysical data in a 2d numpy array. My target is to filter just one trace data and plot it.
I am able to do it, but I need to switch my axes.

**This is what I have for now:**

[image]

So the shape is: (436,1771).

And this is what I have done:

```
    x = arr[:,1]
    
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,'k-')

    ax.set_xlim(0,500)
    
    plt.show()
```

Now that I have my trace, I want to switch my axes so I can see the trace vertically, but I´m having problems doing that and I get errors.

```
x2 = np.swapaxes(x,0,1)
```

I get an error saying " numpy.AxisError: axis2: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1".
I understand that this is because the shape of the array.

So, how can I reshape my arrar into (1771,436) and transpose the data?

Comment: Change to : `x2 = np.swapaxes(arr,0,1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is 1-dimentional array after

```
x = arr[:,1] # x.shape == (N,)
```

so you can't swap axes

For future if you want "keep dims" use

```
x = arr[:, 1, None] # x.shape == (N, 1) # see np.newaxis
```

To solve your problem do that

```
x = arr[:,1]
X_axis_data = x
Y_axis_data = np.arange(x.size)
plt.plot(X_axis_data, Y_axis_data, 'k-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something along these lines?

```
plt.plot(arr[:,1], range(len(arr[:,1])),'k-')
```

Instead of pushing all the Y coordinates, I put all your Y-data as X data and want with a linear scaled axis along the Y-axis done with the range() command. If you just put Y-data, it will assume range(len(Y-data)) as X-data, which is what happens in your example.
feel free to correct me if there is a mistake